# Splitting on the columns of a dataframe with more than two whitespaces

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to split all the columns of a dataframe with more than two whitespaces since all the columns have the same format. I know how to do the same on one or a few columns but stuck at implementing the same code on all the columns.  The code below works for one column. Would really appreciate any help on this.

```
df2 = df1['Col 1'].str.split("\s{2,}",expand = True)
```

Comment: You should provide a sample input.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with sample input and expected output so that we can better understand your question. On first read, it seems like you want to loop through the columns and use your split on each but it's hard to know

Comment: All the columns of the dataframe has values in this format: AB   1 1   345, separated by multiple spaces.  I want to split the columns with atleast 2 spaces as the separator.  So here the output would have 3 columns with values as 'AB' in Col1, '1 1' in  Col2 and '345' in Col3.

Answer (score 1):

simply do this:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split("\s{2,}",expand = True))
```

Comment: I used this code but I am getting this error - ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index.  It seems the lambda function doesn't take setting the index.